# Set textView text in navigation drawer fragment from another activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, settext

This is my first time posting so bare with please.

I'm trying to set the text of a textView item in the navigation drawer fragment from another activity.

I've tried:

```
public class SomeActivity{
...
...
NavigationDrawerFragment.textViewName.setText("words"); 
} 

public class SomeActivity{
...
...
NavigationDrawerFragment frag = (NavigationDrawerFragment )
getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("NavigationDrawerFragment");

frag.GetTextFromActivityMethod("words");
}
```

and I get a null pointer exception and class not loaded (NavigationDrawerFragment) error in debugger.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, I'm not an Android developer, but you've made a commendable effort for your first question, however to better debug your issue, it would be helpful if you posted a stacktrace. Telling us its a Null Pointer is helpful, but we need to know from where to better debug your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try SharedPreference, here is a sample for your case:

```
public class SomeActivity{

    NavigationDrawerFragment.textViewName.setText("words");
    SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);

    Editor editor = pref.edit();
    editor.putString("WORDS", b);
    editor.commit(); 
}

public class SomeActivity {

     NavigationDrawerFragment frag = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
 getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("NavigationDrawerFragment");

     SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);

    String words = pref.getString("WORDS", null);
    textView.setText
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, that project got scrapped but I'm sure I can use this somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

From main activity you can set the fragment drawer's text view value. I have set it and it works well!

In navigation Drawer Bar

```
public TextView test_text;
test_text = (TextView) viewtype.findviewbyid(R.id.xyz);
```

In the main activity

```
String ABC = preference.getString(key);
test_text.setText(ABC);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, that project got scrapped but I'm sure I can use this somewhere else.